# How to use Opencv Region of Interest(ROI) in Caffe with python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, deep-learning, caffe

I'm working with Caffe framework and python and i take out some part of an image with these:

```
image = cv2.imread(picture_address)
roi = picture[ y:y+hight,  x:x+width]
```

And as I just notice opencv save image as **numpy.ndarray** BGR(instead of rgb).

When i tried to pass this region of interest to Caffe with :

```
transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))
transformer.set_mean('data', mean_array)
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformer.preprocess('data', roi)
out = net.forward()
```

I've get wrong prediction from Caffe, but when i take out that part and save it as a file and use :

```
image = caffe.io.load_image(picture_address)
```

I will get right prediction. so i get the `type(image)` of above code and it is `numpy.ndarray` too (some said it is **datum** type and tried to **convert** it but it is not) so both code save image as numpy, but when i print out the numpy array ,first one (Opencv) elements are in 0-255(integer) range and second one (numpy) is between 0-1(float) , and both array have same dimension`(width,height ,color_channels)`. when i did `cv2.imshow(ROI)` i saw same image but Caffe do different prediction.

**My question is**: How can i change Opencv numpy to Caffe numpy to get the true Prediction?

**Edit(Thanks to @Shai comment):**

I did

```
a = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)/255
```

but when i do `print a[0][0]` i get

```
[ 0.91764706  0.9137255   0.94509804]
```

from OpenCV matrix and

```
[ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
```

from Caffe numpy which is correct. Are dimension changed ? I get really confused.

**EDIT2 :** 
After `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` the two matrix look like same but in deep inspection, opencv look like :

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 **[ 0.90196079  0.90980393  0.95686275]** different row
 [ 0.90196079  0.90980393  0.95686275]
 [ 0.90196079  0.90980393  0.95686275]
 [ 0.90196079  0.90980393  0.95686275] ...
```

And Caffe look like :

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 [ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]
 **[ 0.90588236  0.9137255   0.96078432]** different row 
 [ 0.90196079  0.90980393  0.95686275]
 [ 0.90196079  0.90980393  0.95686275]
 [ 0.90196079  0.90980393  0.95686275] ...
```

Maybe it is why prediction is different. but look same in `cv.imshow()` .

Comment: convert to `dtype='f4'` and divide by 255.0

Comment: You might also want to `.copy(order='C')` to make sure you get a contiguous array

Comment: @Shai , Thank you sir. I did what you have suggested but it return different result. I've updated question with results.

Comment: are you resizing the image? if so, make sure you use the same sampling/resizing method.

Comment: @Shai , no sir. resizing happen in OpenCV before taking out the ROI, so both image are in the same size and both working in same image. and after that no per-processing happen.

Comment: @Shai, RGB order were different, i used **cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)** and matrices became same. but it is funny still different prediction with same imagnet network. despite that , i should thank you for helping me.